# Should "Recommend a fish for my tank" questions be titled for differentiation, and if so, how?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Regarding "[What other fish would be a good addition to my tank?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1573/what-other-fish-would-be-a-good-addition-to-my-tank)".

The information included in **the question is very specific** (the tank volume, current residents, environment, etc.), **but I think the title of the question is too generic**. Based on the topic, **we are likely to see many questions titled similarly, but with different specifications / scenarios**.

We have similar, properly differentiated (IMHO) titled questions:

- [Can I put any other fish in with a male betta?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1524/can-i-put-any-other-fish-in-with-a-male-betta)
- [Choosing a second fish for a lone goldfish](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1211/choosing-a-second-fish-for-a-lone-goldfish)
- [Which freshwater schooling fish tolerate non-fish best?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/982/which-freshwater-schooling-fish-tolerate-non-fish-best)
- [Which shrimp will co-exist with my loaches and schooling fish?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1409/which-shrimp-will-co-exist-with-my-loaches-and-schooling-fish)

Questions:

- Should the title of the question be altered / differentiated?
- If so, how?
- Should we establish some broad guidelines?

I am not knowledgeable enough about aquariums to answer this question; I am simply identifying what I perceive as a definite potential issue going forward.

Comment: Hmm... yeah, I don't think I have a good answer to this. I think it's a reasonable sort of question to ask, in general, but the odds of people having very similar circumstances can be low. Having said that, I wouldn't want to discourage the ask.

Comment: I'm not recommending discouraging others from asking; I'm thinking more along the editing lines, where the title is too broad, but the question is specific; how should we as a group try to re-word these sorts of titles to give them the best distinction?  As it stands, the main "question" in... question... has a title that is much too broad.

Comment: I knew that, I just don't know how to do that either. :)

Comment: I actually feel that chat is a better place for many (not all) of these questions. Even if they're not too localized, they're highly open to opinion, since there are literally thousands of fish species in the trade. I don't see much difference between "recommend a fish" and "what's your favorite fish".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Questions:
>
> - Should the title of the question be altered / differentiated?

Yes, that title is too generic, and gives minimal cues to readers.

> - If so,how?

I would add a few details of the parameters the OP is operating under, within reason.  I'm not aquarium expert, so I may be missing something, but at the very least I'd add the tank size, and that the OP is looking for smaller fish (a conclusion I arrived at from "I want to add something smaller than a pink kisser.", although my lack of expertise in aquariums may lead me to erroneous assumptions).

Perhaps "What other smaller fish would be a good addition to my 60 gallon freshwater tank?" might work, but I'll defer to the aquarium experts.

> - Should we establish some broad guidelines?

I wouldn't go overboard on guidelines, but generally, I think *some* clarifying details should be incorporated into the title, even if it is just tank size.  I see it as a courtesy to people who might be interested in answering.

Comment: Based on this, I changed it to `Which smaller fish to add to a 60-gal. tank of danios, corydoras and tetras?`, which is just long enough without being overkill.